# What's the difference between p:menuitem's url and outcome attributes?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menu-items

According to the [Primefaces 6.2 user guide](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf) the attributes stand for

> Name | Default | Type | Description
>
> [...]
>
> url | null | String | Url to be navigated when menuitem is clicked
>
> [...]
>
> outcome | null | String | Navigation case outcome

where "outcome" is a synonym of the description for `url`. I would like to avoid using them wrongly.

Comment: I would summarize it as: use url for navigation to external place, outcome for application internals.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

- `outcome` refers to a JSF page in your application or a navigation rule defined in your `faces-config.xml`
- `url` simply opens the given address, which could be on another website.

Using `outcome` is a great feature, because if the targeted JSF page does not exist, the link is not produced, so you will not have a 404 response when clicking on it.

Comment: That's too similar to @Melloware's answer to be a separate one. You're also ignoring the criticism expressed in the comments to not define navigation cases in `faces-config.xml`.

Comment: no, it's different. @Melloware said to use outcome, you must define it in faces-config.xml which is not true. And I don't agree with criticism about faces-config.xml, because in some cases, defining these rules are useful.

Comment: I agree with @fxrobin and deleted my answer.